# Newbie at python qt; setlayout() seems to prohibit the .self prefix?

Tags: qt, class, python-2.7, pyside

I am a python newbie/hobbyist hoping to make python programming into my next career.
I purchased and I have read through page 119 in the Summerfield book "Rapid Gui Programming with Python and QT". I hit a roadblock and was wondering if you could give me some guidance.
My questions are as follows:
Why is it not allowed or necessary to insert "self." as a prefix before each of the widgets below?

For example, if I add the prefix "self." to the line "title = QtGui.QLabel('Title')", I get the following error message: NameError: global name 'title' is not defined

I read in the Summerfield book on "Python gui Programming with qt4" that "setlayout()" reparents the widgets so that Form is the parent. I think he was indicating that the use of "setlayout()" makes the prefix ".self" unnecessary.

But if you don't use "self." as a prefix, how do you point to a widget?
For example, If my using setlayout made "Form" the parent, my function "fn_okButton01_clicked(self):" should be able to get the text value of "titleEdit", but I can't figure out the right way  to get the text value.

I tried using "print **self**.titleEdit.getText()", and "print **Form**.titleEdit.getText()"  Neither worked.  When I tried using the latter, the error message was:  AttributeError: 'Form' object has no attribute 'titleEdit'
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
                Marc
```

Here's the code I have been working with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import (Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton)

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        okButton01 = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        cancelButton01 = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        okButton01.clicked.connect(self.fn_okButton01_clicked)

        title = QtGui.QLabel('Title')
        author = QtGui.QLabel('Author')
        review = QtGui.QLabel('Review')

        titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        authorEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        reviewEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        hbox01 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox01.addStretch(1)
        hbox01.addWidget(title)
        hbox01.addWidget(titleEdit)

        hbox02 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox02.addStretch(1)
        hbox02.addWidget(author)
        hbox02.addWidget(authorEdit)

        hbox03 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox03.addStretch(1)
        hbox03.addWidget(review)
        hbox03.addWidget(reviewEdit)

        hbox00 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox00.addStretch(1)
        hbox00.addWidget(okButton01)
        hbox00.addWidget(cancelButton01)

        vbox0 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox0.addStretch(1)
        vbox0.addLayout(hbox01)
        vbox0.addStretch(1)
        vbox0.addLayout(hbox02)
        vbox0.addStretch(1)
        vbox0.addLayout(hbox03)
        vbox0.addStretch(1)
        vbox0.addLayout(hbox00)

        self.setLayout(vbox0)    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Data Input Fields')    
        self.show()

    def fn_okButton01_clicked(self):
        print self.titleEdit.getText()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you create are assigned to local variables. To access them later you must assign them to the instance of your class. For example, place

```
self.titleEdit = titleEdit
```

at the end of your initUI function. As an alternative, you can also retrieve the object that triggered the signal with

```
self.sender()
```

Comment: 1.Thank you. 2) How can I "paste" the value from one of the "fields" into another?  I tried the following unsuccessfully in def fn_okButton01_clicked(self):
        strText = self.sender().text
        print strText
 Also, where can I find the "rules" for how to use the widgets?  For python's "rules", i.e., how it works, I go to python.org.  Where can I go for similar info re Qt and Python?   thanks again,  Marc 
        self.authorEdit.text = strText

Comment: Dear Thomas:  I figured out (by guessing and experimenting) how to "paste" the value from one field into another, but I still would appreciate it if you could tell me what the url is where I can get directions about how to use the qt widgets in python.  Thanks again,  Marc

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Maybe something like: [PyQtWiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki). I can also recommend the book  _Rapid_ _GUI_ _Programming_ _with_ _Python_ _and_ _QT:_ _The_ _Definitive_ _Guide_ _to_ _PyQt_ _Programming_ by Marc Summerfield. The [PySide site](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) may also help as it is quite simmilar.

Comment: Thank you for replying again.  If I were using WxPython, and trying to use wxButton, I could get good instructions from:   http://www.wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php, and I wouldn't need to know any C or Java to understand the page. Is there an analogous page for Python programming with qt?  My son, an engineer, told me that I should learn qt instead of wxPython, which he said is older technology.  The online docs at PyQtWiki and the PySide site seem to presume that you know some C or Java, and I don't.  The wxPython online docs only require python. Should I give up qt and learn wxPython instead?

Comment: Hi Thomas. I forgot to put your name in the comment I posted a second ago.  Please reply when you hae a chance.   Marc

Comment: Not sure about how to answer this. Generally I think Qt or PyQt/PySide is the superior framework, but I'm not sure which is better for you. Maybe the wxpython dokumentation is better. Still, I think I would just buy the Summerfield book, but I'm not very impartial because I've used Qt a lot and wxWindows way back. Maybe you should discuss this with your son ;)